# bash > $(cmd)と`cmd`の違い

Tags: bash

動作環境: CentOS 6.5 + bash

bashでコマンドの結果を変数に入れる時

```
val=$(cmd)
```

と

```
val=`cmd`
```

の書き方があるようですが、この二者の違いはあるのでしょうか? 単に好みの問題でどちらかを使えばいいものでしょうか?

片方にはできて、もう片方にはできないような処理があるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash(1)` から引用します。

> Command Substitution
>
> Command  substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  There are two forms:
>
> $(command)
>   　　or
>      `command`
>
> When the old-style backquote form of  substitution  is  used, backslash retains  its  literal  meaning  except when followed by $, `, or . The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.
>
> Command substitutions may be nested. To nest when using the  backquoted form, escape the inner backquotes with backslashes.

```
$ echo `echo \``
bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
$ echo `echo \\\``
`
$ echo $(echo \`)
`

$ echo `echo `echo "xyz"``
echo xyz
$ echo `echo \`echo "xyz"\``
xyz
$ echo $(echo $(echo "xyz"))
xyz
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。backquoteの扱いが変わってくるのですね。また、old-style backquote formということで、こちら"`"で囲う方は古いスタイルなのですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

ネストの深い$(cmd)形式と`cmd`形式の使い方例です。
`cmd`形式ではネストが増えるにつれ、バッククォート(`)をエスケープする`\`の個数が2の累乗個ずつが増えます。

```
echo `echo \`echo "xyz"\``
echo `echo \`echo \\\`echo "xyz"\\\`\``
echo `echo \`echo \\\`echo \\\\\\\`echo "xyz"\\\\\\\`\\\`\``
echo `echo \`echo \\\`echo \\\\\\\`echo \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\`echo "xyz"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\`\\\\\\\`\\\`\``

echo $(echo $(echo "xyz"))
echo $(echo $(echo $(echo "xyz")))
echo $(echo $(echo $(echo $(echo "xyz"))))
echo $(echo $(echo $(echo $(echo $(echo "xyz")))))
```

私事ですが、以前は`Bourne Shell`縛りでshスクリプトを書いていました。※今は違います。
現在も`Bourne Shell`ユーザが少なからずいらっしゃると思いますので、ネストを増やした例を挙げました。